# Container Creation Fails with Jib after upgrading to 2.7.0.Final

Tags: quarkus

The container creation fails with the message
"Error": "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/deployments/run-java.sh": stat /deployments/run-java.sh: no such file or directory: unknown",

The whole process works fine when I change the Quarkus version from 2.7.0.Final to 2.6.3.Final.

I am using jib to generate the image. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the change in base image that went in with Quarkus 2.7. See the relevant [entry](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-2.7#jib) in the migration guide.
The new base image does not contain the `/deployments/run-java.sh` shell script.

You can go back to the base image used in previous Quarkus versions using `quarkus.jib.base-jvm-image=fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk11-jre`

If one needs to add their own startup script, then script can be added to the created container image as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#including-extra-files). Additionally the [quarkus.jib.entry-point](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-container-image-jib_quarkus.jib.jvm-entrypoint) needs to be set to the path of the startup script.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix the issue? Is there a way to set the entry point in correct way? In migration guide it does mention change in images, but doesn't specify anything else.